# Do variable declaration and definition have the same meaning in JavaScript and C?

Tags: javascript, c, variables, declaration, definition

Based on what I know in JavaScript variable declaration is announcing that a variable exists and giving a name to it (I don't know if it also allocates memory or not).

`var x;`

and defining a variable is assigning a value to it

`x = 5;`

But in C and I think other programming languages, variable declaration is giving details about the variable like it's name and type and definition is where in the memory the variable is stored, So `int x;` is both declaration and definition of a variable.

So is the meaning of definition and declaration different in these programming languages?

Comment: You're trying to compare apples with apache helicopters my man...

Comment: In C `extern int var;` is a declaration which states that `var` is defined elsewhere, and similarly with function prototypes, which declare that the function has been defined somewhere, and in both cases the linker will find them.